# SMTPAuthenticationError Rails Mailing Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, development-environment, contact-form

Why am I getting a 500 error? I have not been able to successfully receive an email into my gmail account in developent 
Here what is in my server log:

```
          tarted POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2015-04-06 12:23:42 -0500
          Processing by ContactsController#create as */*
          Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"2rAtjm6kGBtqrHwLM1oCdrjzJUhYuSR2eX+/4fJpgcCF2TvDs+jKtOPgXmSPOV/eQ9eIRlftynyB6VZKqHw4Ew==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"ahdiwhfjfhew", "email"=>"iahfiwhef@yahoo.com", "message"=>"kfbjwefawjbfjwbeakfekwjfjk3fwoefowqou"}, "commit"=>"Send Message"}
          DEPRECATION WARNING: `#deliver` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5. Use `#deliver_now` to deliver immediately or `#deliver_later` to deliver through Active Job. (called from create at /Users/corneliusmurphy/spartan_strength_and_power/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:9)
          Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail_form-1.5.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb (0.6ms)

         MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 83.5ms

         Sent mail to neil.murphy0600@gmail.com (817.1ms)
         Date: Mon, 06 Apr 2015 12:23:42 -0500
         From: ahdiwhfjfhew <iahfiwhef@yahoo.com>
         To: neil.murphy0600@gmail.com
         Message-ID: <5522c11eb5b6b_596c3fc77b83f2c055624@CorneliussMBP3.mail>
         Subject: My Contact Form
         Mime-Version: 1.0
         Content-Type: text/html;
         charset=UTF-8
         Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        <h4 style="text-decoration:underline">My Contact Form</h4>


        <p><b>Name:</b>
        ahdiwhfjfhew</p>

        <p><b>Email:</b>
        iahfiwhef@yahoo.com</p>

        <p><b>Message:</b>
        kfbjwefawjbfjwbeakfekwjfjk3fwoefowqou</p>


       Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 902ms

       Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt4U):app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was Because Google was an issue with Google security feature that can be enable/disabled within Gmail